# AWS Route53 CloudFormation Template - How to set a default GeoLocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

So, I have a template that sets up Location based DNS routing, and it's working, but I can't find a way to set the default geolocation, as you can through the Route53 UI on the AWS Console.

Anyone know how? Here's my snippet:

```
"GeoServerDNSRecordSet" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "Properties" : {
     "HostedZoneName" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [{ "Ref" : "BaseDomain" }, "."]]},
     "Comment" : "Weighted record set for GeoServer",
     "RecordSets" : [
      {
        "Name" :  { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["wms.", { "Ref" : "BaseDomain" }, "."]]},
        "Type" : "CNAME",
        "HealthCheckId" : { "Ref" : "GeoserverEUWest1HealthCheck" },
        "TTL" : "900",
        "SetIdentifier" : "GeoServer DNS eu-west-1 DEFAULT",
        "GeoLocation": {"ContinentCode" : "EU"},
        "ResourceRecords" : [
          { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["wms.eu-west-1.", { "Ref" : "BaseDomain" }]]}
        ]
      },{
        "Name" :  { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["wms.", { "Ref" : "BaseDomain" }, "."]]},
        "Type" : "CNAME",
        "HealthCheckId" : { "Ref" : "GeoserverAPSoutheast2HealthCheck" },
        "TTL" : "900",
        "SetIdentifier" : "GeoServer DNS ap-southeast-2 Oceania",
        "GeoLocation": {"ContinentCode" : "OC"},
        "ResourceRecords" : [
          { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["wms.ap-southeast-2.", { "Ref" : "BaseDomain" }]]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want is that EU recordset to be default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
"GeoLocation": {"CountryCode" : "*"}
```

> We recommend that you create one geolocation resource record set for which the value of CountryCode is * to cover geographic locations for which you haven't created resource record sets and to cover IP addresses for which Amazon Route 53 can't identify a location.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets_Requests.html#change-rrsets-request-country-code